# Getting User's Location Without Permission

Tags: geolocation, location, google-geolocation

[This website](http://webkay.robinlinus.com/) finds my location with a reasonable presicion. If i use mobilephone the website finds my exact location. If it is possible without asking permission why most of them asks me before getting my location? Isn't it makes personal security vulnerabilities?

Comment: The website you posted doesn't find anything even close to my location. It uses the IP to estimate the position of your POP. The same can be done with mobile phones in a much more exact way, because the cells are distributed in a much finer mesh. You are mixing that up with getting the exact geolocation by using GPS or similar means, and that's a function you can have the browser return IF the user gave permission to the browser to supply that data.

Comment: BTW, just read what it says below the map on that website: "Webkay uses the Google Geolocation API to locate you. This is an educated guess and never as accurate as a GPS Location."

Answer (score 2):

From the same page you gave us:

> Webkay uses the ***Google Geolocation API to locate you***. This is an
>   educated guess and ***never*** as accurate as a GPS Location. The accuracy
>   depends on your ***location*** and also on your ***connection type***. If you are
>   on a ***mobile network*** expect an ***error of up to 50km***.  This example just
>   tries to demonstrate how accurate a website can guess your location
>   without asking you for permission to access your GPS.

A site only needs permission, if it wants to enable your device's GPS. Also, without the permission, the guessed location is heavily dependent on your mobile carrier signal and IP address. If you are in a location with a lot of mobile towers, the location (obviously) will get more precise.

A site can use the information from all near mobile towers around you to triangulate the position and guess where you are. Think of it like a mesh.

For example: I am using a computer to write this now and the location is easy ~100km off, because it has only my IP adress to estimate the location.